# Passing arguments to nested functions with ellipses in R language

Tags: r

Following one tutorial(in my native language), I'm trying to write a function `decorate_string` , which will be able to do this:

```
decorate_string(pattern = "123", "abc")            # "123abc321"
decorate_string(pattern = "123", "abc", "def")     # "123abc def321"
decorate_string(pattern = "123", c("abc", "def"))  # "123abc321" "123def321"
decorate_string(pattern = "123", "abc", "def", sep = "+")    # "123abc+def321"
decorate_string(pattern = "!", c("x", "x"), collapse = "_")  # "!x_x!"
decorate_string(pattern = ".:", 1:2, 3:4, 5:6, sep = "&")    # ".:1&3&5:." ".:2&4&6:." (вектор длины 2)
```

TO BE SHORT: It collapses strings with a separetor and segregate it with pattern on the left and reversed pattern on the right.

I've done this:

```
decorate_string <- function(pattern, ...) { 
  fock <- function(x, pattern, rev_pat){
    x <- paste(pattern, x, rev_pat, collapse = "")
    return(x)
  }
  rev_pat <- paste(rev((strsplit(pattern,NULL))[[1]]), collapse = "")
  #a <- paste0(..., sep=" ")
  a <- sapply(paste(..., sep=" "), fock)
  return(a)
}
```

But it tells me, that argument `sep` corresponds to severel arguments. I guess, it tries to pass the `sep` argument in the nested function too, right? But nested function doesnt ask for this argument! I DO NOT want the `fock` function to recieve my param. I want only `sapply` to recieve this params!! Whats should i do? Thanks

Comment: Add sep as a parameter in your function.  That way it isn't included in the dotlist.

Comment: @Dason Sorry, that was my bad! I DO NOT want the nested function to recieve this param! I want `sep` to be used once in `sapply`!

Comment: No the issue is that if you don't have sep as a parameter then it gets passed into the dotlist. So when you're using paste(..., sep = " ") it's like you're saying `paste(something, sep =",", sep=" ")` so you're getting an error because R is like "hang on you can't try to use the sep parameter twice".  But if you define it as a parameter in your original function then it won't be included in the dotlist.

Comment: I'll add that I really haven't read much into what you're doing but that seems to be the issue you're having.

Comment: @Dason Sir, are You sure, You understand, that i dont want the `sep` to go into `fock` function. But if i initialize `sep` in `fock`, this will make the `sep` value be able to change!

Comment: I never said anything about the fock function.  That isn't where the issue is. The issue is in your line `a <- sapply(paste(..., sep=" "), fock)`.  In that paste statement there is a `sep` being passed in through the dots and then another sep being specified.  You either need to remove the sep from the dotlist manually or have it be a different argument that is passed in in which case it will never be in the dotlist to begin with.

Comment: @Dason Thanks! Could You please post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dason proposed:"
I never said anything about the fock function. That isn't where the issue is. The issue is in your line `a <- sapply(paste(..., sep=" "), fock)`. In that paste statement there is a sep being passed in through the dots and then another sep being specified. You either need to remove the sep from the dotlist manually or have it be a different argument that is passed in in which case it will never be in the dotlist to begin with"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the author of the question correctly understood the work of the operator (...)

```
decorate_string <- function(pattern, ...) {
   paste0(pattern, paste(...), stringi::stri_reverse(pattern))}
```